# Search a table looking for labels

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to search a table looking for all the labels in that table. When the JavaScript function finds a label I want to set it's visibility to false.

My html code looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboEvaporatorChoice" runat="server" class="cboBoxes"
Width="130px" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="clearLabels(MainTable)"></asp:DropDownList>
```

My function is called on a drop down lists `onchange` event which then passes the table that holds all the labels I want to hide.

I am not sure what my JavaScript code should look like... This is all I have:

```
 function clearBox(ID) {
 var element = document.getElementsByTagName(ID);
 }
```

Comment: It is a lot easier to answer a question about accessing HTML with JavaScript when you show people the HTML and not some ASP that generates some HTML.

Comment: Johnny, please note that there is a difference between "visibility:false" and "display:none". "visibility" leaves whitespace where the item is. "display" removes it from the layout completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function clearLabels(ID) {
    var labels = document.getElementById(ID).getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
        labels[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Or if you are using jQuery

```
$('#' + ID).find('label').hide();
```

Comment: @zzzzBov - yah, i am a big fan of jQuery.